# Python Cartesian plane plot and line

Tags: python, math, plot, line

I want to create a cartesian plane in python that looks similar to the [attached image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udGu1.png), where I have 2 sets of coordinates e.g. (7,7) (17.4,20), and a line going through, the information I would have to create this graph would be the gradient, y-intercept and the 2 sets of coordinates. Is this possible and if so, how?

Comment: Do you have any code attempted?

Comment: `matplotlib.pyplot`.  You need to read about that.  It's a bit surprising you didn't already fine it; it's the primary plotting package in Python.

Comment: @TimRoberts I have read up on `matplotlib.pyplot` but I couldn't find documentation on how to make a cartesian plane with it

Comment: You have a terminology problem.  EVERY 2D plot is a Carteisan plane.  I suspect what you are asking about is the grid lines.  Matplotlib can do those.  https://matplotlib.org/3.5.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.grid.html

Answer (score 2):

Matplotlib can do just about anything, if you can figure out how to spell it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(x):
    return 1.1*x - 1

x = np.arange(-30,30)
y = f(x)

# Plot the line.

plt.plot( x, y, 'r' )

# Plot the two points.

plt.plot( 7, f(7), 'bo' )
plt.annotate( 'A', (7, f(7)-4), color='blue' )
plt.plot( 17, f(17), 'ro')
plt.annotate( 'B', (17, f(17)-4), color='red' )

# Draw the axes.

plt.axhline(0,color='black')
plt.axvline(0,color='black')

# Draw the grid lines.

plt.minorticks_on()
plt.grid( True, 'minor', markevery=2, linestyle='--' )
plt.grid( True, 'major', markevery=10 )

plt.show()
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: is it possible to put the numbers on the axis instead of on the edges?

Comment: That seems like the least important issue here.  Clearly, you could use `annotate` to place those values, if you absolutely need them.